# How to union two array references containing array references in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

Let's say I have an array reference which looks like -

```
my $arrayref1 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];
```

and, I have another array reference as -

```
my $arrayref2 = [[1,2], [3,4], [7,8]];
```

How do I achieve something like this -

```
push @{$arrayref1}, @{$arrayref2};
```

such that arrayref1 will look like this (excluding array references containing common elements) -

```
$arrayref2 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]];
```

Comment: The title of the question does not describe what you are trying to do. You are trying to take the union of two sets of sets.

Comment: You seem to want elements that already exist excluded from the new data, but you don't mention it in your description. Is that correct?

Comment: @Borodin, Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @vp8: Then please edit your question to explain the problem properly.

Answer (score 3):

Use a hash of hashes to represent the existing elements of the union:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $arrayref1 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];
my $arrayref2 = [[1,2], [3,4], [7,8]];

my %set;
undef $set{ $_->[0] }{ $_->[1] } for @$arrayref1;

my @union = @$arrayref1;

for my $pair (@$arrayref2) {
    push @union, $pair unless exists $set{ $pair->[0] }{ $pair->[1] };
    undef $set{ $pair->[0] }{ $pair->[1] };
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@union;
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do as you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $arrayref1 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];
my $arrayref2 = [[1,2], [3,4], [7,8]];

my $result = meld($arrayref1, $arrayref2);

print join (', ', map { sprintf "[%d,%d]", @$_ } @$arrayref1), "\n";

sub meld {
    my ($a1, $a2) = @_;
    my %uniq;

    $uniq{"@$_"} = 1 for @$a1;

    for ( @$a2 ) {
        my $key = "@$_";
        next if $uniq{$key}++;
        push @$a1, [ @$_ ];
    }

    $a1;
}
```

#### output

```
[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]
```